# Define foreign key in Entity Framework only with Id property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am struggling with Entity framework. The thing I want to acheive is to have an entity with only Id which will define a foreign key without actual reference to the related entity. How can it be achieved?

Class.cs:

```
public class Class {
    Guid Id {get; set} // this is my primary key
    Guid ProfessorId {get; set; } // this has to be id of professor which is a foreign key
}
```

Professor.cs

```
public class Class {
    Guid Id {get; set} // this is a primaty key of professor and it should constraint ProfessorId
}
```

I'm using fluent api. I cannot add any virtual properties to above classes (basically i cannot modify them), so how the mapping should be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you cannot modify entities but you **need** to add at least one  **navigation property**. It is necessary for Entity Framework in order that it understand the relationship. 
In your code `ProfessorId` is only a **scalar property**.

The only other way is to execute sql command directly from your context

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("...");
```